# Why restore doesn't send event authenticationSucceeded when using ember-simple-auth?

Tags: ember.js, ember-simple-auth

I need to get current user when a session is authenticated. I have implemented the service currentUser

```
import Ember from 'ember';

const { inject: { service }, isEmpty, RSVP } = Ember;

export default Ember.Service.extend({
  store: service(),
  user: null,

  load() {
    return this.get('store').find('user', 'me').then((user) => {
      this.set('user', user);
    });
  }
});
```

And I call it in route/application.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import ApplicationRouteMixin from 'ember-simple-auth/mixins/application-route-mixin';

export default Ember.Route.extend(ApplicationRouteMixin, {
  session: Ember.inject.service(),
  currentUser: Ember.inject.service(),

  init: function(){
    return this._super();
  },

  actions: {
    invalidateSession() {
      this.get('session').invalidate();
    }
  },

  sessionAuthenticated() {
    alert("sessionAuthenticated");
    this._super(...arguments);
    this._loadCurrentUser().catch(() => this.get('session').invalidate());
  },

  _loadCurrentUser() {
    return this.get('currentUser').load();
  }

});
```

When a user login or signup, the event `authenticationSucceeded` is called but when the session is restored in my authenticator, the event is not called. I need to call it because I need to reload user information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that the `sessionAuthenticated` is triggered on restore. You need to load the user in your `beforeModel` hook.

```js
// ...
beforeModel() {
  return this._loadCurrentUser();
}
// ...
```

You can take a look at the official docs for setting the current user [here](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth/blob/master/guides/managing-current-user.md)

Comment: If I do that, I have to check every time that a user open my app if the session is authenticated, is that the best way?

Comment: I will say yes, but to be honest, I cannot think of an another way to implement this.

Comment: It works very well, I suppose that is the only way to perform an update of current user info using ember-simple-auth. If you want to update your answer, I have use this to avoid always call even if your session is not authenticated: `beforeModel() {
    let accessToken = this.get('session.data.authenticated.userToken');
    if (this.get('session.isAuthenticated') && !Ember.isEmpty(accessToken)) {
        return this._loadCurrentUser();
    }
  },`